# Azure Functions: SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

Tags: python, rest, post, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to post a data to a REST API but it is throwing the below error:

```
[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]
certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

If I hit the REST API url using the **curl --insecure dummyurl.com** then it is returning something.. but I my aim is to hit the url using the azure functions only.
So my question is-- Should I seek certificate from the REST API owner?? or I have to integrate `--insecure` to my url ??
I am using python for the development.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can add/manage the TLS (private/public cert) under App services depend on your TLS scenarios , refer to [Add and Manage TLS cert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate) , alternative you can disable the SSL verification in your python code but not recommended in your actual environment.

Comment: give me some to validate it... I'll share the updates very soon.